# Check text input if email already exist or empty

Tags: html, jquery, json, ajax, post

I want to get the value on txtEmail input and check if it already used once text input is out of focus. Only have one email address suppose to be used which is john.doe@example.com. If email already exist, it will return an error message that it already exist. It will also return an error message if the textfield is empty

"Checkemail.php"

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if ($_REQUEST['email'] == 'john.doe@example.com') {
    echo -1;    
} else {
    echo 1;
}
?>
```

Scripts.js

```
    document.getElementById("txtEmail").addEventListener("focusout", outOfFocus);

function outOfFocus(){
    var txtEmail = $("#txtEmail").val();
    console.log(txtEmail);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"checkemail.php?email=<email>",
        data: txtEmail,
        
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Success!");
        },

        error: function(){
            document.getElementById("#emailError").innerHTML = "Email address already used!"
        }
    })
}
```

Email.html

```
<label for="lblEmail">Email : </label>
<input type="email" id="txtEmail">
<label for="emailError" id="emailError"></label><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

"blur" is the event you are wanting - there isn't a "focusout" as far as I know, unless you are using some library that has that

Also, when sending a POST request, you don't need the query string (i.e the line should just be `url:"checkemail.php"`, since the data will just be sent in the POST body)

You should also access the variable server-side with $_POST, not $_REQUEST

Likewise, if you are referencing things by POST variable names, you might have to send a key-value object, rather than just the string. Just copy an example from the jQuery docs. You could also use the $.post method, which is a shorthand for setting the $.ajax method as post manually

If you do all of those steps, that should get you most of the way there